# i want to update composer from a cloned laravel project

Tags: laravel

I have a project built in **laravel 5.8** and I seems to heave update my laravel installation on my pc to 6.0 when I run `composer update`, it throws an error

my `composer.json` is below

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "kalnoy/nestedset": "^5.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "realrashid/sweet-alert": "^2.0",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack": "^1.0",
        "watson/active": "^4.0",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your `composer.json` file and add the error to your question.

Comment: What`s the error it is throwing? Share with us the log

Comment: try ```composer install``` for first time usages - if you don't have a vendor folder

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: the error i get is   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35

Comment: I think this is because some package laravel, can you give a full error so I can check which package does not meet the requirements of laravel 5.8

Comment: @user7310495 what is the update?

Comment: am yet to get it fixed

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because some of the dependencies in your `composer.json` requires lower version or higher version of `laravel/framework v5.8.35` .

Here is a tip, go through your `composer.json` file if there are dependencies not being used by your application, delete them from your composer.json file.

Then run

`composer update`

If it still not solve your problem , try installing the lower version of `laravel/framework`

for example ,

```
composer require laravel/framework:1.*
```

or try installing latest version of `laravel/framework`

`composer install laravel/framework:5.3.*`